# Prove $(∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))) → ((∃x(¬P(x))) → (∃x(Q(x))))$ using natural deduction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

Hi guys I'm trying to learn natural deduction in predicate logic and I'm struggling with this proof.

> $(∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))) → ((∃x(¬P(x))) → (∃x(Q(x))))$

I'm trying to follow my textbook but don't have many examples likes this one. Any help would be appreciated.

So far I have two assumptions:

> $(∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x)))$ and $¬((∃x(¬P(x))) → (∃x(Q(x))))$

Comment: I am not sure why you didn't pick off the $(∃x(¬P(x))$ as an assumption and try to prove $∃x(Q(x))$ (rather than your 2nd assumption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sketch of the proof:*

From$$\exists x(\lnot P(x))$$
you'll get $$\lnot P(t)$$ for some $t$.

From $$\forall x (P(x)\lor Q(x))$$ you'll get $$P(t)\lor Q(t)$$
by using Spec (specialization).

You should now be able to conclude $Q(t)$, and by using Rule $\exists$, you get $\exists x Q(x)$.

This is just an outline, and you should be able to convert this to a *formal natural deduction* proof. The idea is: "if for all $x$, either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ holds, and for particular $x=t$, $P(t)$ does not hold, then $Q(t)$ holds."

---

Showing $$\vdash (∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))) → ((∃x(¬P(x))) → (∃x(Q(x))))$$ amounts to showing $$\{∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x)), ∃x(¬P(x))\} \vdash ∃xQ(x)$$
using **deduction** theorem.

Comment: First of all you've go to persuade the OP to change his assumptions to match ours.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Done!